# Error when passing paramater to pentaho report query

Tags: sql, pentaho

I'm trying to pass the ${SubLocationId} parameter to a query used in a Pentaho report as indicated below

```
SELECT
    UTD.Vehicle,
    UTD.Location,
    UTD.SubLocation,
    UTD.HourCreated,
    UTD.VehicleId,
    UTD.SensorPosition,
    (SELECT Pressure FROM DailyTyreData WHERE Created = UTD.Created AND VehicleId =         UTD.VehicleId AND UTD.SensorPosition = SensorPosition) AS Pressure,
    (SELECT Temperature FROM DailyTyreData WHERE Created = UTD.Created AND VehicleId = UTD.VehicleId AND UTD.SensorPosition = SensorPosition) AS Temperature
FROM
    (SELECT
        DTD.ExternalReference AS Vehicle,
        DTD.Location,
        DTD.SubLocation,
        DTD.HourCreated,
        DTD.VehicleId,
        DTD.SensorPosition,
        MAX(DTD.Created) AS Created
    FROM 
        DailyTyreData DTD
    WHERE
        DTD.SubLocationId = ${SubLocationId}
    GROUP BY
        DTD.ExternalReference,
        DTD.SubLocation,
        DTD.Location,
        DTD.HourCreated,
        DTD.VehicleId,
        DTD.SensorId,
        DTD.SensorPosition) UTD
ORDER BY
    UTD.Created
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to preview the report

```
org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: Failed at query:

at    org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:258)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SQLReportDataFactory.java:171)
```

The parameter was added to the input parameters in the parameter section of the report designer. Is there any reason why this is happening?

Comment: where exactly is the datasource defined? in the parent or sub report?  (assuming this is a subreport? )  If you deselect the query and just display $SubLocationId in the report as a field in itself can you see the value passed in?

Comment: Yes this is a sub report, the data source is defined in the parent. I can see the value passed when I $SubLocationId as a field in the report.

Comment: The query is populating a line chart and it looks like it is working when I'm passing ${SubLocationId} = 2 (This is returning some data), but is failing when I'm passing ${SubLocationId} = 1 (This is returning no data). Obviously the line chart doesn't like an empty resultset.

Comment: interesting. not sure how you handle no data in charts, is the no data message set in the chart?

Comment: Yes the no data message is set, looks like I would somehow have to determine if there is data myself and find a work around that way. Thank you in any case for your help, it got me thinking in the right direction. +1

Comment: cool. Sounds like a bug tho really, worth raising on jira.pentaho.com if this is an up to date version of the software!

Answer (score 0):

Ok the parameter was passed as expected but the query returned no results causing the line chart to break the report when previewing.